# Matlab Engine API OpenSingleUseFunction() and OpenEngineFunction() timeouts in 2 minutes

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, matlab-engine

When I launch the Matlab tool in Windows machine, the tool launches but it is in "Initializing" phase for 4-5 minutes. The tool will not respond to any user commands.

The issue could be due to usage of remote license.
The usage of remote license or modifying anything in remote server is not possible right now.

After 4-5 minutes of initialization the Matlab tool works fine and I am ok with this behavior.

But the real problem is while launching Matlab tool using engine.c APIs such as OpenSingleUseFunction() or OpenEngineFunction(), the tool is launching and then goes to idle state.

**Since Matlab is in "Initializing" phase for 4-5 minutes, the engine terminates the Matlab session after 2 minutes timeout and returns a MatlabEngine nullptr.**

The 2 minutes timeout is not given by user to the engine APIs.

**So is there any way to change this timeout value in engine APIs?**